# What's the idiom for doing something in vain

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I'm looking for an idiom to describe a task where you put in a lot of effort but in vain.

Comment: The answer would vary depending upon what what preventing the success.

Comment: Is this for when what you’re doing is a waste of time or when it had a good chance of succeeding but just failed?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/209267/17956

Comment: Your question was closed for lack of clarity but seems clear and answerable. I suggest it should be reopened. 

It is a **Sisyphean** task:

>[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sisyphean)  
*Sisyphean*:  
used to describe a task that can never be completed

The word relates to the fate of Sysiphus, who was condemned to roll rocks up a hill only for them to roll back down

Comment: The question is not clear and answerable because there is not enough information here about **why** the task is in vain. A sisyphean task is not flogging a dead horse. The potential variety of answers for such a vague question indicates that more detail is needed.

Comment: Another idiom is "closing the barn door after the horse has bolted." But that's only applicable if you're doing it in vain because it's too late.

Answer (score 1):

**Flog a dead horse** is a common idiom in such situations.

[flog a dead horse](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/flog+a+dead+horse)

[The Free Dictionary]